Upgraded Amplify from cli, now cannot use graphql to load s3 data Error 400 cognit identity pool not found
Working on a website for a client and I upgraded amplify cli and pushed a model. Now my s3 data is not loading. Database is managed by amplify. I checked all my auth keys and none of them are expired.
I noticed that the identity pool in myschema doesn't exist. I cant find a way to change it in amplify since its autogenerated. Going into authentication in the amplify backend just spins so I cant access it.
